# how to terminate thread sendMsgToServer when exit is sent from the server side

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class ThreadSandbox {
     //static volatile boolean runLoopX = true;
    static AtomicBoolean runLoopX = new AtomicBoolean();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {                
                try {
                    BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    String userInputStr = "";                                    
                    do {
                            System.out.println("Enter text for thread 1:");
                            userInputStr = userInput.readLine().trim();
                            System.out.println("User Input for thread 1: " + userInputStr);                            
                    } while (userInputStr.equals("e") == false && runLoopX.get()== false);        
                } catch (Exception e) {System.err.println(e.toString());}
                runLoopX.set(true);                
            }
        });
        final Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    String userInputStr = "";                                    
                    do {    
                            System.out.println("Enter text for thread 2:");
                            userInputStr = userInput.readLine().trim();
                            System.out.println("User Input for thread 2: " + userInputStr);
                    } while (userInputStr.equals("e") == false && runLoopX.get()== false);        
                } catch (Exception e) {System.err.println(e.toString());}
                runLoopX.set(true);                
            }
        });
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                do {
                    if (runLoopX.get() == true) {
                        thread1.interrupt();
                        thread2.interrupt();
                    }
                } while (runLoopX.get() == false);
            }
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
            thread3.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {System.err.println(e.toString());}
    }
}
```

Issue: 
If I enter "e" for thread1 input then thread1 terminates but thread2 is still running and If I enter "e" for thread2 input then thread2 terminates but thread1 is still running.

How do I terminate both threads when "e" is entered in either threads?

Answer (score 0):

you should synchronize your threads for the inputs.

but a synchronized String and made all of your threads check this string before trying to read anything

so if this string has the value "e" then the thread will terminate it self. if not just read the input but the value in the string and continue.

make sure about this String be synchronized and I would like to make it volatile

---

to more specific this is a bad example of threads ! if one thread will lock the application until the user enters some data. the other thread should wait in the wait queue for more performance. 
in this case all of your threads will be kept in the ready queue and this will consume the CPU utilization.

to solve this problem try to use Lock and Conditions.

---

this is a fast pesedo-code to solve the problem on sockets :

```
public class ThreadSandbox {
public static  syncrnized boolean continueWork = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {   while(continueWork){
                try {

                    socket.setSoTimeout(5 *1000);
                    //READ str FROM SOCKET 
                    if(str.equals("e")) {
                        continueWork =false;
                    }
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e.toString());
                }
            }           
        }
    });

    final Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {   while(continueWork){
                try {

                    socket.setSoTimeout(5 *1000);
                    //READ str FROM SOCKET 
                    if(str.equals("e")) {
                        continueWork =false;
                    }
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e.toString());
                }
            }           
        }
    });

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
}
```

Comment: i am actually doing this for sockets where i want to use one socket to listen for incoming messages and the other one to send messages.  so the app needs to end when user from client or server input e.

Comment: ok the all of your threads should should loop over a static synchronized variable like ` while(continueWork) { } ` and this variables all threads can set and get so if any of your threads.
also you need set time out for your socket.
I will edit the answer for sockets.